# Getting the size of a struct with dynamic variables?

Tags: c++

I have a struct with a dynamic array:

```
struct test{int* arr;};
```

After allocating space for the `arr` array(`arr=new int[100]`), using `sizeof` returns 4 bytes, which is the size of the struct without the array elements. Is there another built-in function like `sizeof` that can return the size while keeping dynamically allocated space into account? Or do I have to do this myself?

**+**

I need this because I want to make it easier to save/load the contents of the struct to/from a file.

Comment: No, `sizeof` is a compile-time operation. You need to track the number of elements you allocate, and do the maths.

Comment: You should not tag the question C and C++ when the code is clearly C++ and not valid C. Since you are using C++ why do you want to do raw memory manager.

Comment: the sizeof will return the size of data inside the struct, and it is a pointer to int this is 4 bytes it's true, if you want to get all of it you must know the length of the dynamic array and multibly by length*sizeof(int) , you can use wrapper for the array that contain the pointer and the length or just use something like vector or CArray or CPtrArray if you use MFC on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to get the memory usage due to an object and the other objects it points to, because it's not a well defined concept.

- Two objects might point to the same `arr` block. Are they both responsible for consuming the memory?
- What about recursion if you have an array of structures containing pointers? What about a cycle?
- Maybe `arr` points to the stack. Does that count as using memory?
- `malloc` might round up the requested allocation size, or allocate internal bookkeeping structures. Do such effects count?

Some operating systems do provide a facility to retrieve the argument to `malloc` (or sometimes a rounded-up value, because the underlying system might genuinely have no use for the original argument), but in standard C and C++, POSIX and in general practice, you are responsible for tracking allocation sizes yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I think you are out of luck. The size returned by `sizeof` is the size of the pointer which cannot lead to the correct size of what it points to (in your case a dynamic array).

I suggest you to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It has a `size()` member function that returns the number of elements in use:

```
struct test {
    std::vector<int> arr;
}

test x;
// ...
x.arr.size();
```

Comment: I think "dynamic" rules out `std::array`

Comment: `size()` is not redundant in `std::array`, as the `Container` concept requires it.

Comment: @rightfold, it **might** be redundant, for the user of `std::array`, in case you are hardcoding the number of elements the array must have. I'm sure there is a good reason as to why it has that member function, though.